# Url links from database in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios5

How to get urllink data that are stored in database in iphone sdk ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following Code may be help you.

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URL"]]];

    // Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSLog(@"Your Data=%@",response);

    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Comment: am not using json is there any way to get with out json am getting the other data from the database but am unable to get my urllink data from datbase

Comment: Try to add this comment in your Question so that you can get a better answer suitable for you.

Try to Post Some Code that you have tried Already so that We can check What is the issue there. Visit this link for a complete tutorial http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775277/not-getting-response-from-webservice check this link